# Error while trying to import the MMWormhole.h to my WatchkitExtension InterfaceController.h

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, watchkit, apple-watch

im trying to use the MMWormhole Library to comunicate my app with the apple watch. I have imported the MMWormhole library via CocoaPods, but i keep getting an error while trying to import the MMWormhole.h file to the InterfaceController.h of my Watchkit Extension. I have imported the libraries in "Linked Frameworks and Libraries". In my Application i don't get any errors when i import the MMWormhole.h into any class.

this is my IntefaceController.h of my Watchkit Extension:

```
#import <WatchKit/WatchKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MMWormhole.h>


@interface InterfaceController : WKInterfaceController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKInterfaceLabel *latitudeLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKInterfaceLabel *longitudeLabel;

@end
```

i get an error on the MMWormhole.h import. Thanks

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be something like `MMWormhole/MMWormhole.h`?
Check what are the autocomplete suggestions as You typed `#import <M`

Comment: I've tried that, but it doesn't work either. I have it imported on my main ViewController just fine, i think it might be problem with the watchkitExtension. When i do the `#import <M` and wait for it to autocomplete, it doesn't show me anything related to the MMWormhole Library.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a Framework: File > New > Target > Cocoa Touch Framework
- Then download the ZIP of MMWormhole and drag the MMWormhole.h and MMWormhole.m files into "YourFramework".

In "YourFramework.h" write:

```
#import <YourFramework/MMWormhole.h>
```

- Set the Target Membership of the MMWormhole.h to "YourFramework" and **Public**.

At the end import the framework in all swift-files you want to use it.

```
import YourFramework
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Podfile, create another target for your WatchKit Extension and add `pod 'MMWormhole'` like this.

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'SomeOtherLibrary', '3.10'
    pod 'MMWormhole'
end

target 'MyApp WatchKit Extension' do
    pod 'MMWormhole'
end
```

Run `pod update` and now `#import <MMWormhole/MMWormhole.h>` will work for both targets.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your Podfile with this line:

```
link_with 'MyApp', 'MyWatchExtension'
```

where 'MyApp' and 'MyWatchExtension' are names of your targets. Then `pod update` will link your pods.

Also you can link your pods manually in "Build settings" tab for your watch extension's target. Type 'pod' in search bar and compare results with your main app's target, then add missing links for watch extension.

Build settings for watch extension must look like this: [image]

Comment: Thank you! thank you very much! now it works as is supposed to! thanks for your time!